# How Do I Incorporate Ajax into a CreateView?

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have a CreateView...and it works fine in the traditional sense.  I'm trying to convert it essentially to an AJAX for submit because the user can attach files to the form, and I'm trying to avoid a form submission failure based on the user's mistakes.  Here is my CreateView...

```
class CreateProcedureView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = NewProcedure
    form_class = CreateProcedureForm
    template_name = 'create_procedure.html'

   def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "cancel" in request.POST:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Procedures:procedure_main_menu'))
        else:
            self.object = None
            user = request.user
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            file_form = NewProcedureFilesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            files = request.FILES.getlist('file[]')
            if form.is_valid() and file_form.is_valid():
                procedure_instance = form.save(commit=False)
                procedure_instance.user = user
                procedure_instance.save()
                list=[]
                for f in files:
                    procedure_file_instance = NewProcedureFiles(attachments=f, new_procedure=procedure_instance)
                    procedure_file_instance.save()
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                form_class = self.get_form_class()
                form = self.get_form(form_class)
                file_form = NewProcedureFilesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                return self.form_invalid(form)
```

As stated it works just fine the way it is.  What I'm trying to figure out is how can I best convert this to an AJAX type of approach?  Here's what I have so far...

Here's my AJAX...

```
 $(document).ready(function (){

  var token = '{{csrf_token}}';

  $("#forms").on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newprocedure = '{{ newprocedure }}';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
            url: "{% url 'Procedures:ajax_posting' %}",
            data:$("#forms").serialize(),
            datatype:'json',
            success: function(data) {
              console.log("here");
              if (data['success'])
                 alert("successfully added to favorites")
            }
        });
   });
 });
```

And here is the view that I am trying to call...

```
def ajax_posting(request):
    user = request.user
    data = request.POST
    form = CreateProcedureForm(user,data=data)
    if request.method=='POST':  
        return JsonResponse({'success':'True'})
    else:
        print(form.errors)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I can see it is calling the view because the print(form.errors) is showing me a bunch of errors for required fields and I would expect that because the form doesn't seem to be processing after I fill it out and click submit absolutely nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.  I'm new to the whole AJAX thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your earlier view to process. It just need a little tweaking.

On submit, you would want to instatiate your form as a JS FormData in your ajax script

```
data:  FormData(forms[0])
```

You can receive the data with django thus

```
data = request.POST
```

And then instantiate it with your django form for processing thus

```
form = RegForm(data=data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  So that I understand you're saying to put the on my Ajax script, and the data = request.POST on my model and the form = RegForm(data=data) where exactly?  On the model as well?

Comment: Model? Not model. They should go in your view

Comment: my bad.  Long day.   That's what I meant...view....It seems to be working...at least it's submitting.  I'm still testing.  But I did notice that your one suggestion is causing an error...FormData(forms[0])...is causing an Unexpected token '[' error.  It seems to be working but I can't figure out how to solve that error.

Comment: I made a few changes and it's a lot closer to what I think it should be doing....I'm updating my code examples above...the bottom line is that this is now capturing my form more accurately, but it's not submitting it.

Comment: I have it narrowed down.  If I use your suggestion...data:  { FormData(forms[0]) }, it works....but I have a syntax error...If I use data:$("#forms").serialize(), the form will not submit.  How should I address this?

Comment: @Chymdy...Your suggestion works but it bypasses the ajax_posting view...it submits the form but that's it.  When I use the serializer....it correctly references the ajax_posting view...but it's not validating the form.

Comment: Which view do you intend to submit your data to?

Comment: I intend to submit it to the CreateView.

Comment: Ok then, point your ajax url to the url of your create view.

Comment: I've mostly got it working now.  I know a naive question but is there some way to get the AJAX form errors back to the Django Template?  I've got a solution using JQuery to append to the DOM...but is there some way to just insert the errors into the form as it would normally be processed?

Comment: If there is an error... Return the error as a http or json response.